# why do you have to stringify values using webpack DefinePlugin?

Tags: webpack

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is necessary. For example if I supply:
`plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      '__DEV__': true,`

it does in fact come out as a `true` boolean. In posts I've ready they talk about the value appearing "as-is" in code, but I have no idea what that means. There appears to be no difference. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess that define plugin does simple string replace, so it makes sense that values are strings too.